# wanted to edit answer, but was not allowed to do so

Tags: support, review, specific-answer

I was reviewing an late answer in the review queue:

[Weird stuff happening with complex numbers on a ti-84](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658185/weird-stuff-happening-with-complex-numbers-on-a-ti-84/938830#938830)

(a first answer by a new user "marius")

and wanted to edit the answer (removing expletives) 
but somehow was not able to do so (the edit option was greyed out)

flagged the answer instead,  but why could I not edit the answer?

Comment: There was an edit suggestion standing for that answer from about that time. Try now.

Comment: I edited to remove the expletives.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6480/editing-now-completely-blocked-while-an-edit-is-pending

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate. As Asaf and Martin said: there was a pending edit suggestion on that post, and since you cannot review edits yet, the edit box is grayed out to prevent two potentially conflicting/overlapping edit suggestions from being entered.